# Set data to localstorage

Tags: javascript

I have localstorage where i want to set my data. But i have problem. Data is not setting to localstorage it just changing. How to make data added but not changed.

```html
    const titleProduct = '<? echo $title ?>';
    
    var session = {'products': [],'state': true};
 session.products.push({title: titleProduct});
  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(session));
```

Comment: Can you be more accurate, what do you expect and what happens? Changing is setting, setting can also be changing... if you add, than it has to be changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to follow the following procedure:

1. Load data
2. Change data
3. Store data

This can be done as follows:

```js
const rawData = localStorage.getItem("my-data") || "[]";
const data = JSON.parse(rawData);
data.push(new Date().toISOString());
localStorage.setItem("my-data", JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(data);
```

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ujdzs3b9/), as the code snippet component on StackOverflow does not support `LocalStorage` operations.